# Hiding the table when the user touches on uiscrollview

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I added UIScrollView inside a UIview,And I added one button to the scrollview ,When I press that button it is generating table inside a uiscrollview.Now my problem is i want to remove that table when the user touches on anywhere inside a scrollview.I tried by using touches began method but for scroll view it is not working.Please help me if any one knows

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

If the user taps the button, the touch will not be received by the scroll view. Instead, create a method like the following and add it as a target of the button.

```
- (void)hideTable {
    [yourTableView setHidden:YES];
}
```

When you create your button, or in `viewDidLoad` if it is loaded from a nib, add the method as a target of the button:

```
[yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(hideTable) 
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 0):

`touchesBegan` method will not work unless you subclass.

`UITapGestureRecognizer` is a solution for you. You can use it as follows.

...

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didTapScrollView)];
[scrollView addRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
[tapRecognizer release];  //If not ARC

-(void)didTapScrollView
{
    [tableView removeFromSuperview];
}
```